# How can I remove contacts from a phone without removing them from my Google account?

Tags: contacts, google-account

I have a 2nd phone (LG Stylo 6) that I will only use for some specific things & do not want all my contacts on it.  I hadn't realized sync was on when I entered my email. I shut sync off but when I go to remove contacts on the Stylo 6 I get a message "This contact will be removed from Google Contacts & all your synced devices."
I don't want to remove the contact from my Google contacts, I just want to remove it from this particular phone. Is this possible? Or do I have to come up with a new email for this phone so my Google contacts aren't effected?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good answer, but it's how I ended up doing it:

Settings > Accounts > Google > select account > Disable contacts sync

Then delete all the contacts by clicking selecting one for example and then on the three dots and select all -> delete.

Disclaimer -> do not sync the contacts again.
If you want to then you will have to go back to an older version by using the web view contacts.google.com